# post data to external database from ios via php

Tags: php, mysql, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I found a tutorial online on how to post data into from ios into external database using php. Below is the code and it works fine it inserts into a table called test that has three columns id, name, message. name is varchar and message is text if that makes any difference.

```
-(void)postMessage:(NSString*) message withName:(NSString *){

if(name !=nil && message !=nil){

    NSMutableString *postString = [NSMutableString stringWithString: kPostURL];

    [postString appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"?%@=%@", kName , name]];

    [postString appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"&%@=%@", kMessage, message]];

    [postString setString:[postString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:postString]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    postConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:YES];

}

}


-(IBAction)post:(id)sender{
[self postMessage:messageText.text withName:nameText.text];
[messageText resignFirstResponder];
messageText.text = nil;
nameText.text = nil;
}
```

In my app i need to post more than two fields so I altered the code and added an extra column in the table called test(varchar 30). Below is my new code which now does not work. No data is being entered into the database. Why is this is there an error i cant see?

```
-(void)postMessage:(NSString*) message withName:(NSString *) name withTestvarchar:(NSString *) testvarchar{

if(name !=nil && message !=nil){

    NSMutableString *postString = [NSMutableString stringWithString: kPostURL];

    [postString appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"?%@=%@", kName , name]];

    [postString appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"&%@=%@", kMessage, message]];

   [postString appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"&%@=%@", kTestvarchar, testvarchar]];

    [postString setString:[postString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:postString]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    postConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:YES];

}

}


-(IBAction)post:(id)sender{
[self postMessage:messageText.text withName:nameText.text withTestvarchar:testvarcharText.text];
[messageText resignFirstResponder];
messageText.text = nil;
nameText.text = nil;
testvarcharText.text = nil;
}
```

I can't understand why this won't work any suggestions? / can you see the error?

Thanks

Comment: Did you implement the delegate methods of `NSURLConnectionDelegate` for example, there is `connection:didFailWithError:` that may help you.

Comment: Yes i did if i change `[postString appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"?%@=%@", kTestvarchar, testvarchar]];`then it appears in the message column of the database. It seems no matter what i try i can only add two variables into the two columns, i can't get past two. Take away testvarchar works fine, replace testvarchar with message works fine. I can't get it to do three